# urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Tags: python, web-scraping, ssl-certificate, urllib

Learning to scrape a website. "https://www.localharvest.org/" for now. trying to urlopen but gives the above mentioned error. Windows 10 64-64 bit, Python 3.7.1

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.localharvest.org/'
response = urlopen(url)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org

Comment: I hae the trouble in 'windows'. I have checked the post previously. The suggested answer is not applicable to me as I cannot find "certificates" file anywhere in my python installation.

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: How did you solve it? I am facing the same challenge in Win 10.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04, this helped me

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Comment: finally I found a soluton!!!! than you!

Answer (score 0):

Via PIP - bash
    pip install --upgrade certifi

[timon.web: Fixing CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/fixing-certificate_verify_failed-error-when-trying-requests_html-out-on-mac/)