# Python Slackbot not Showing as active and Not responding

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

The slackbot is not showing as active and not responding. I have used ngrok to set up tunneling from my localhost to allow for the slack bot to be verified. On slack it shows that the request URL has been verified. I have also subscribed to slack events.

I am following, https://medium.com/developer-student-clubs-tiet/how-to-build-your-first-slack-bot-in-2020-with-python-flask-using-the-slack-events-api-4b20ae7b4f86, to get this bot working. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
import os
from threading import Thread
from slack import WebClient


# This `app` represents your existing Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hello there", "hey"]

SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ['SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET']
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']
VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ['VERIFICATION_TOKEN']

#instantiating slack client
slack_client = WebClient(slack_token)

# An example of one of your Flask app's routes
@app.route("/")
def event_hook(request):
    json_dict = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    if json_dict["token"] != VERIFICATION_TOKEN:
        return {"status": 403}

    if "type" in json_dict:
        if json_dict["type"] == "url_verification":
            response_dict = {"challenge": json_dict["challenge"]}
            return response_dict
    return {"status": 500}
    return


slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(
    SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET, "/slack/events", app
)  


@slack_events_adapter.on("app_mention")
def handle_message(event_data):
    def send_reply(value):
        event_data = value
        message = event_data["event"]
        if message.get("subtype") is None:
            command = message.get("text")
            channel_id = message["channel"]
            if any(item in command.lower() for item in greetings):
                message = (
                    "Hello <@%s>! :tada:"
                    % message["user"]  # noqa
                )
                slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id, text=message)
    thread = Thread(target=send_reply, kwargs={"value": event_data})
    thread.start()
    return Response(status=200)


# Start the server on port 3000
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(port=3000)
```

Comment: "app_mention" helped me a lot. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

This was the error code that I was running into:
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)>.

This brought me to this StackOverflow thread:
[Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org)

Running the certification file in the python folder allowed the slack bot to interact with the channel. The bot is now working but does not show as active.