# Unable to obtain cookie. Try cookie generation later

Tags: cookies, asf

I met issues while bulk downloading Alos Palsar DEMs from https://search.asf.alaska.edu
The error comes out when I run a script.py which contains my downloads:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18362.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Name>cd Downloads

C:\Users\Name\Downloads>python download-all-2020-10-01_05-44-48.py
No existing URS cookie found, please enter Earthdata username & password:
(Credentials will not be stored, saved or logged anywhere)
 > Cookiejar is bunk: None
Username: username
Password (will not be displayed):

IMPORTANT: There was a problem communicating with URS, unable to obtain cookie.
Try cookie generation later.

C:\Users\Name\Downloads>
```

Does any one has an idea how to fix it? Literature on this issue seems very rare.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. So, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671292/12344383). Adding this line before de, worked

```
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Also, you need to put the .csv file generate at https://search.asf.alaska.edu at the end.

```
python download-all-2020-10-01_05-44-48.py path/csv.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Before downloading ASF data, please carefully check everything below:

1. Verify your email address by clicking on the link NASA sent you.
2. go to https://search.asf.alaska.edu and login to agree EULAs.
3. go to https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/users/new to agree EULA.
   Wait for 5 minutes, and the server will refresh the status of your account and give your account permission to download data.
   Reference is here:[How do I download ASF data?](https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?t=3495)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but I was able to download it using admin mode.
For example, open VS(visual studio) in admin mode, or open cmd in adm mode.