# Python 3: urllib module basic function not working

Tags: python, http, url, module, request

I'm a new python developer and I watched a few tutorials on YouTube explaining the functions and the uses for this module, but I cannot get it to work. I installed the module via pip so I don't think that is the issue.

```
import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')

print(x.read())
```

**Output:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1342, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mike/PycharmProjects/urllib/main.py", line 8, in 
x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1385, in https_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1345, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)>

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org/53310545#53310545)

Found the solution: install the "Install Certificates.command" in the python 3.9 folder

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be an SSL certificate error.

probably a program on your pc is blocking SSL certificates.

Comment: Any solution that you will give to solve OP's problem?