# Getting error while installing IBM_WATSON library in Python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, ssl-certificate, ibm-watson

While running

```
pip install ibm_watson
```

I am getting the below error. I am using the latest anaconda and the latest python version 3.9.2.

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ibm-watson/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ibm-watson/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ibm-watson/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ibm-watson/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ibm-watson/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ibm-watson/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ibm-watson/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ibm_watson

ERROR: No matching distribution found for ibm_watson

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems unrelated to the ibm-watson library, judging by the error cause in the stacktrace:

```
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'
```

First check if OPENSSLDIR (or the corresponding environment variable in your OS) is set to the correct path containing your tls certificates. If you are using macOS, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310545/15385777

You can also try updating pip to the last version and installing **certifi** first before checking if ibm-watson can be installed:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install certifi
pip install ibm-watson
```

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: I have checked the OPENSSLDIR path mentioned doesn't exist. But I have tried to install OpenSSL and added a path in environment variable. And also install git. But Still i am unable to install ibm_watson. Please can you guide me. If i have done any mistake in configuration

Comment: What's your OS and pip version?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and pip version is "pip 21.0.1 from c:\users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)"

Comment: You were able to install `certifi` with `pip`?

Comment: Really Thanks Vanderlei. It works suddenly after uninstalling Git 3rd party application. Needs to install OPENSSL certificate.