# How to import csv as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, import

I have a csv file which is located on my computer, the path looks like:
Macintosh HD/somefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder/file.csv

However when I try to import that csv as a dataframe in pandas using the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Macintosh HD/somefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder/file.csv", sep =";")
```

PyCharm returns an error claiming there is no such directory or file. OKay, I insert a direct link where the same csv is located online, in this case the code looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://disk.yandex.ru/d/yaPJSq26gFvxHw", sep =";")
```

and now PyCharm says:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

What's wrong in my code and why don't I manage to import that csv directly from my mac?

Comment: Check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338899) answer to get the correct `path` to your `csv` file.

Comment: What does `os.path.exists("/Macintosh HD/somefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder/file.csv")` return?

Comment: This question could you help you out for the second problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a path problem rather than a pandas issue. Try opening the same file with the built-in `open()` function. To get the correct path to navigate over to the directory containing the csv file and write `pwd` in the terminal (for macOS). Copy this path and just append the `<filename>.csv`

### Possible Solutions

---

1. Move the `file.csv` to the same folder as the python script or Jupyter Notebook and then simply use `pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep = ";")`.
2. The URL which you shared redirects to a page but doesn't download the csv file directly. If you have the file available in s3 or gs, try using that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative path by putting the csv in the same folder with the script or notebook you are trying to read the csv.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
```

or in a folder that is in the same folder with the script/notebook:

```
df = pd.read_csv('name_of_the_folder/file.csv', sep=';')
```

The link you are using is not the url of the csv file, it is the url of the web page you can download the csv so it won't work.