# Python: Able to read rss url using chrome but unable to read using python

Tags: python, rss-reader

```
from datetime import datetime
import feedparser
import requests

def ESXi():
    NewsFeed = feedparser.parse("https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/rn_rss.xml")
    print(NewsFeed)
    num = len(NewsFeed.entries)
```

```
{'bozo': 1, 'entries': [], 'feed': {'summary': '<h1>Access Denied</h1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/rn_rss.xml" on this server.<p>\nReference #18.1c1d2017.1633578424.39d379a4'}, 'headers': {}, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'version': '', 'bozo_exception': SAXParseException('mismatched tag'), 'namespaces': {}}
```

Able to check the rss feed using chrome but got this output while using python.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the agent is not authorized, you can use the following to change the agent just after all the imports:

```
feedparser.USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"
```

After that you should not have any problems.