# Error: metadata-generation-failed × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> crepe

Tags: python, model

when I'm installing a model, it runs an error. I am not sure whether the following codes help or not. I've tried a lot of the solution from others, but still not working:) By the way, I've installed `crepe`, but, same error.

```py
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/30/5bmmkvz55kn9rnmd0h46hjyw0000gp/T/pip-install-x0j44toc/crepe/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
          urlretrieve(base_url + compressed_file, compressed_path)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
          with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1362, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1322, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>
      Downloading weight file model-tiny.h5.bz2 ...
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> crepe

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

P.s. The hint is not helpful, dude:)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50236117/5320906) answer your  question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, well, I've tried it. But the certification is failed :(