# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when calling load_dataset() from seaborn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn-0.12.x

I'm trying to load a dataset using **seaborn.load_dataset ** function

```
from seaborn import load_dataset

df = load_dataset('penguins')
```

But it produces the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)>
```

The dataset is listed in [seaborn data repository](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data), so I have no idea what is going wrong.

Seaborn version is **0.12.2**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org)

Comment: It helped! Thank you very much!